# bootstrap select not showing items

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flask, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am trying to use [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) in my python flask web page.  Following is the code I currently have.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/sl-slide.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-select.min.css')}}">

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}" ></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-dropdown.js')}}" ></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-select.js')}}" ></script>

       
</head>
<body>
    <section id="about-us" class="container main">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span8" >
            <div class="blog">
              <div class="blog-item well">
                <a href="#"><h2>Heading2</h2></a>
                <select class="selectpicker" id="select_county" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary">
                    <option>County1</option>
                    <option>County2</option>
                </select>

                <select class="selectpicker" id="select_event" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary">
                    <option>event1</option>
                    <option>event2</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
       });
    </script>
</body>
```

Although data-live-search of select works, select is not showing any of the items other than the selected one.

[image]

I even refresh in `$(document).ready()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Why do you have two ready events in your application?

Comment: sry amit, I should have removed the one inside the header. edited now

Comment: Can you please help me understand that why are you refreshing select box by following code? $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

Comment: @amit, it was suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270462/bootstrap-select-dropdownlist-not-showing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below HTML is working fine, SECTION end/closing is missing in your html, Kindly remove script of document.ready as well.  Refer below html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <section id="about-us" class="container main">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8" >
                <div class="blog">

                  <div class="blog-item well">
                    <a href="#"><h2>Heading2</h2></a>
                    <select class="selectpicker" id="select_county" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary">
                      <option>County1</option>
                      <option>County2</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="selectpicker" id="select_event" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary">
                      <option>event1</option>
                      <option>event2</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button">


                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey  i checked it's not me, even with my upvote it becomes 0. when i remove upvote its -1 :(

Answer (score 4):

Move the  Js files and the `<script>` , at the end before close `body` tag:

```
<body>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}" ></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-dropdown.js')}}" ></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-select.js')}}" ></script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        style: 'btn-default',
        size: false
    });
});
</body>
```

Comment: Can you suggest how this change will resolve the issue, please?

Comment: @Melik, it didnt help

Comment: He needs to resize the select button to the default size  i guess this will solve the issue

Comment: @RoshanaSheri change select button style to " btn-default "

Comment: @Melik, it just changes the appearance :(